# prevent text in a table cell from wrapping --with empty colum

Tags: static

Does anyone know how I can prevent the text in a table cell from wrapping? This is for the header of a table, and the heading is a lot longer than the data under it, but I need it to display on only one line. It is okay if the column is very wide.

The HTML of my (simplified) table looks like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <div>Really long column heading</div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div>Really long column heading</div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div>Really long column heading</div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div>Really long column heading</div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div>Really long column heading</div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div>Really long column heading</div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div>Really long column heading</div>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>data</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>data</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>data</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>data</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>data</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>data</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>data</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The heading itself is wrapped in a div inside the th tag for reasons pertaining to the javascript on the page.

The table is coming out with the headings wrapping onto multiple lines. This seems to only happen when the table is sufficiently wide, as the browser is trying to avoid horizontal scrolling. In my case, though, I want horizontal scrolling.

```
th {
white-space: nowrap;
```

}

having issue because i am having a empty table header

Any ideas?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `white-space: nowrap;` to the `<th>` elements.

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/b1e0x672/2/ with some padding just to keep it nice on the eyes. You will probably want to make your CSS more specific than mine so that nothing interferes with its styling.

You may also noticed I applied a vertical alignment to the td elements. If you apply `vertical-align: top;` to your `<td>` elements then they will always begin just under your heading instead of the middle of the table.

Comment: yep its working ! but what pupose you have used vertical align:top  its really important?

Comment: Its not really important its just that removing the vertical align means the columns dont look as good in my opinion. You dont need to keep the vertical align if you want to lay it out differently. Here is an example without vertical align: https://jsfiddle.net/bq5evo54/

Answer (score 5):

```
table th, table td{
  white-space: nowrap !important;
}
```

That do the trick. Remember to add `!important` to override any other white-space style that may affect the one you want to implement.

```css
table th, table td{
  white-space: nowrap !important;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <div>Really long column heading</div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div>Really long column heading</div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div>Really long column heading</div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div>Really long column heading</div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div>Really long column heading</div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div>Really long column heading</div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div>Really long column heading</div>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>data</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>data</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>data</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>data</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>data</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>data</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>data</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: i want to break my td...but save my th ....so  table th{
  white-space: nowrap !important;
}

Comment: well, if you only want the th you can do it like that =D i wrapped everything xD